# inputing details from form to database doesn't work

Tags: php

[image: html code]
[image: php code]

[image: this is what happen when i try to click the submit button, the code will print]
i want to input the data from form to database i'm using xampp

Comment: Please add your code as text and not as images and provide a clear, concise question stating the problem

Comment: FYI- Your code is wide open to SQL injection. Always use `prepared statements` with bound parameters when using user supplied data in your sql

Comment: using `$_REQUEST` rather than `$_POST` means somebody can craft a url in the browser address bar to easily try attacking your app

Comment: _Never_ store passwords in plain text! You should only store password hashes generated using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and to verify a password againts a hash, use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 0):

If your xampp Apache server and MySQL server are turned on, you should be accessing the web pages with "`localhost/proj/`" not with the file directory.

Comment: sorry i'm newbie but i just want to create registration form and connect it to my database but every time i click the submit button the code on my php is printed

Comment: when i open in to localhost/proj/registration.php "Warning: Undefined array key "firstname" in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\registration.php on line 7" this what happen